# How to return **kwargs with double star/asterisk in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Say I have following functions:

```py
def f(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        print(key + ': ' + str(kwargs[key]))

def make_kwargs():
    # My example implementation here
    params = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
    return params # Here is the part I don't know how to do
```

And the functions has to be called in the following way:

```py
f(make_kwargs())
```

However, this will return me the **TypeError**:

> TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I tried:

```py
return **params
```

But the syntax is invalid.

Say I cannot modify function `f()` and the way it is called (`f(make_kwargs())`). The only part I can modify is how I implement `make_kwargs()`. I wonder if there's a way to do that?

Comment: `f(**make_kwargs())`

Comment: Refer this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: If you can't modify `f()`, nor the way it is called, you may be stuck.

Answer (score 5):

`make_kwargs` returns a dictionary, so you are just passing a dictionary to `f`.
You want to unpack that dictionary into keyword arguments like so:

```py
f(**make_kwargs())
```

Comment: Yes, I know this can solve the problem, However, I cannot modify the way it is called:
`f(make_kwargs())`
Only part I can modify is inside function `make_kwargs()`

Comment: The call `f(make_kwargs())` is always invalid for `def f(**kwargs)`, no matter what `make_kwargs` returns. You can not make this code valid by changing the definition of `make_kwargs`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late - but this can be done by redefining `f` using a closure:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        print(key + ': ' + str(kwargs[key]))

def make_kwargs():
    params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return params

def with_kwargs(function):
    def wrapper(kwargs_as_dict):
        function(**kwargs_as_dict)
    return wrapper

# redefine f
f = with_kwargs(f)

# now this works
f(make_kwargs())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still possible to print those values however you'll still get TypeError on the second call.

```
def f(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        print(key + ': ' + str(kwargs[key]))


def make_kwargs():
    # My example implementation here
    params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return f(**params)


f(make_kwargs())
```